Opentext Content Manager (TRIM) update error in DemoDB
I was trying to update record using ServiceAPI /Record get 500 error in the DemoDB

first I upload a file to server using /UploadFile service, it works fine,

then I when I try to update a record using /Record service with some JSON like this


{
"Uri":5762,
"RecordTitle": {
"Value": "My Title"
},
"RecordFilePath": "c:\junk\my file.docx"
}
Then I get a 500 server error.
Furthermore, if I run the same functions with my own test dataset, all works fine.
Can someone shed some lights, appreciate it.
